# yum update error on centos server

Tags: server, centos6, yum

I tried to run "`yum update`" on my server but it gives me an error. Below is part of the output when I type "yum update"

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtidy.i686 0:0.99.0-19.20070615.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-common.i686 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package pytalloc.i686 0:2.0.7-2.el6 will be installed
http://mirror01.idc.hinet.net/EPEL/6/i386/repodata/5d15e6d6e1b58456584beb7bbb0b6     46495aff0da11b1211c208afbddf9a73eed-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERRO     R 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/6/i386/repodata/5d15e6d6e1b58456584     beb7bbb0b646495aff0da11b1211c208afbddf9a73eed-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] P     YCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

Then, I tried typing "`yum clean all`" thinking it would solve my problem. However, it became worst, it gives me another error message and doesn't even show any package that will be installed. (See below).

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, replace, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing all php and reinstalling it again using yum install php php-common.